# Centos 7.9 to Centos 8.4 upgrade

Tags: centos

I have system which is Centos 7.9 but kernel sets has upgraded to 5.4.154(unofficial version) before. Right now i want to upgrade my machine to 8.4. How could i do it? I tried lots of methods . But it has error on some part.

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install epel-release -y
yum install yum-utils
# yum install rpmconf
# rpmconf -a
# package-cleanup --leaves
# package-cleanup --orphans
# yum install dnf
# dnf -y remove yum yum-metadata-parser
# rm -Rf /etc/yum
# dnf upgrade
# dnf install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/centos-linux-repos-8-2.el8.noarch.rpm http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/centos-linux-release-8.3-1.2011.el8.noarch.rpm http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/centos-gpg-keys-8-2.el8.noarch.rpm

# dnf clean all

# rpm -e `rpm -q kernel`

# rpm -e --nodeps sysvinit-tools

# dnf -y --releasever=8 --allowerasing --setopt=deltarpm=false distro-sync

# dnf -y install kernel-core

# dnf -y groupupdate "Core" "Minimal Install"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).